# Conversion of date from one format to another

Tags: c++

How to convert date from one format to another format in C++. 
eg:- I have date in format 01-DEC-12, I want to change in 12012012 (mmddyyyy)
Note I am using strings for all date formats.

Comment: So, you have string format1("01-DEC-2012"); and want string format2 == "12012012"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is not a forum to get an implementation for a given specification. You should show us what you have tried already

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [boost date time i/o](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is some clever code, but I would simply have a table like this:

```
 struct MonthNameToNumber
 {
     string name;
     string number;
 };

 MonthNameToNumber mtable = { { "JAN", "01"}, { "FEB", "02" }, ... { "DEC", "12" } };
```

The rest is just a case of splitting a string into portions and pasting it back together in a different format.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a third-party library for this, rather you want to parse different date formats on your own. If you want to do so, I advise you to define some kind of whitelist of all date-format-strings you allow to occur, e.g.

```
01-DEC-12
12.01.2012
2012-01-12
```

Second step will be to define some general date-format for internal use (e.g. UNIX-Timestamp, time_t struct, ...).

Third step is to provide a parser for each date-format-string: this is the part where you need to write some kind of parser on your own (e.g using basic string-functionalities of C/C++ and/or stringstreams).

Be careful defining your whitelist of allowed format-strings. Defining something like "yyyy-mm-dd" AND "yyyy-dd-mm" ist not a good idea (just imagine the date 2013-12-01 -> is ist 01-DEC-2013 or 12-JAN-2013?)

I definitely would prefer some third-party library, e.g. [boost date time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html). Furthermore if you need this for internal usage only, you should definitely not use strings but one other kind of representation (again something like UNIX-Timestamp or time_t struct).